# Условие : если переменная равна 1 значению массива

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Как выполнить данное условие : `@if (v.id in ViewBag.AnswerID)`

`v.id` - int

`ViewBag.AnswerID` - List

пробовал так

```
@int i = 0
@if (v.id == ViewBag.AnswerID[i])
{
...
@i++
}
```

Но пишет ошибку в `@int i = 0`

Comment: Что за ошибка? Текст ошибки в студию, пожалуйста!

Comment: _"пишет ошибку в @int i = 0"_ -- а в razor после 0 не нужно ставить `;`?

Comment: @Stack, нет, не нужно, `;` ставится только внутри конструкции `@{  }`, `@int i = 0` если после этого поставить `;` - то получим их в разметке. А вообще тут ошибка в синтаксисе, надо было писать так `@{int i=0;}`

Answer (score 3):

```
@if (ViewBag.AnswerID.Contains(v.id))
{
     <text>v.id cодержится в списке</text>
}
```

Comment: Как все просто)) спасибо большое!! С новым годом =)

Comment: @МихаилАкимов, если ответ Вас устраивает, пожалуйста, нажмите галочку рядом с ответом